# can someone help me with this question?

Tags: geometry

A three-dimensional shape is made by taking a cube and cutting off each of its corners in such way so that the cuts is extended to less than halfway along each edge.

Then how many edges does the new shape have?

$(A) \ 12 \\
(B) \  20 \\
(C) \  32 \\
(D) \ 36$

Comment: Can you find the shape you are looking for in [this list of Archimedean solids](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedeanSolid.html)?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Kashmala Hussain,  Welcome to this great platform where you can learn.  I think the link given by #Wouter,  can help you. I just attached the link again. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedeanSolid.html

Answer (score 1):

Cutting up 1 corner results in 3 additional edges. How many corners are there?

How many edges are there originally?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Originally you have $12$ edges right?

When you cut a corner off you create $3$ new edges without removing any of the old edges (since you cut less than halfway along the edge)

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Take a cube and cut each corner in such a way so that the cuts is extended upto half-way of each edge.

This method will create $3$ new edges at each vertex /corner of the cube and the old cube had $12$ edges already.

So at each vertex we are getting more $3$ edges and so the $8$ vertex/corner of the cubes produces more $3 \times 8=24$ edges after cutting in the above way.

We have already $12$ edges previously as a cube has $12$ edges. So total edges after cutting will be

$$24+12=36.$$

Thus the answer will be $36$.